# Basement Bathroom Water Leaking?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, shower

We've had some water leaking in the basement bathroom (no window but has a fan) that rotted out one of the baseboards and caused mold to grow. I ripped it out and replaced the baseboard with pvc board. I ran the water while looking behind the wall to see if there was a leak and didn't find anything. Now that I've patched up the hole I do see some water forming on corner of the tub with a little bit of water dripping down the wall. Is that water still a cause for concern? is it just a poor calk job?

I showed some photos to a plumber and they said it might be a pipe leak? But that it would be expensive to rip out the tile and take a look.

[image]

Comment: You haven't explained where the water is coming from, so it's hard to say. Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. You seem to be asking _us_ whether _your_ bathroom leaks. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Is that piece of 2x4 in the picture holding up the house or just the edge of the tub? Someone didn't do a very good job of drilling the hole there...

Comment: I edited the photo to show where the water is coming from. The 2x4 is holding up the edge of the tub. The water only appears when the shower is on for 10+minutes of time. And you can really only see it when you hold a roll of tp to the corner to see if there is water.

Comment: after taking a look at my shower I did the following

1. Took a level to see if my tub was properly leveled. Found out that it was not and that water was flowing to a specific corner of the tub.

2. Clearing out the water I saw some bubbles and found more water

3. Ripped out that plastic and saw a ton of water underneath. Got everything bone dry

4. Filled the tub with water before inserting the poly foam calk saver.

5. Completed multiple rounds of caulking to  waterproof

I'm currently waiting 24 hours for the caulk to cure before showering and hopefully fixing my problem.